# EasyRTC works only inside same LAN (ICE failed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc, chromium, easyrtc

The problem is that the remote video can seen only if two computers are in same LAN Environment, namely from different ip's the remote video not seen and in the js console I get error `ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details`.

I'm trying to search solution and found only that the problem may be because "ICE Candidates are received before answer is sent RemoteDescription should be set", but i have no idea how to correct it.

In part of other webrtc scripts, RTCMultiConnection for example not have this problem.

Any solution?

EasyRTC - http://easyrtc.com/download/

Running EasyRTC- http://wdd.co.il:8280

**Update**: my onIceCandidate

```
pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
            if (newPeerConn.cancelled) {
                return;
            }
            var candidateData;
            if (event.candidate && peerConns[otherUser]) {
                candidateData = {
                    type: 'candidate',
                    label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                    id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
                    candidate: event.candidate.candidate
                };

                if( iceCandidateFilter ) {
                   candidateData = iceCandidateFilter(candidateData, false);
                   if( !candidateData ) {
                      return;
                   }
                } 
                //
                // some candidates include ip addresses of turn servers. we'll want those 
                // later so we can see if our actual connection uses a turn server.
                // The keyword "relay" in the candidate identifies it as referencing a 
                // turn server. The \d symbol in the regular expression matches a number.
                // 
                if (event.candidate.candidate.indexOf("typ relay") > 0) {
                    var ipAddress = event.candidate.candidate.match(/(udp|tcp) \d+ (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/i)[2];
                    self._turnServers[ipAddress] = true;
                }

                if (peerConns[otherUser].connectionAccepted) {
                    sendSignalling(otherUser, "candidate", candidateData, null, function() {
                        failureCB(self.errCodes.PEER_GONE, "Candidate disappeared");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    peerConns[otherUser].candidatesToSend.push(candidateData);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: I have an if in my onIceCandidate() callback where I check if the remote sdp was already set. When it's not, I store the ice candidate in an array and in my onRemoteSdp callback I set any ice candidates that are present in that array. This works perfectly for me.

Comment: I added onIceCandidate code above, could you see if there is sdp checking?

Comment: It does not check for a remote sdp, it also does a lot of stuff that isn't really necessary. My onIceCandidate does: if (remoteSdpSet) {peerconnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate); }else{ myIceCandidateArray.push(iceCandidate); } That's all.

Comment: Could you upload your WebRTC script?

Comment: No, it belongs to my company and my boss won't allow me to share the source.

Comment: You are right, could you recommend me some good open source webrtc?

Answer (score 0):

If the two clients can reach each other while on the same subnet, but not across subnets, then the problem is invariably that either the supplied list of STUN servers isn't working for you, or you need a TURN server because your clients are behind nasty corporate firewalls or symmetric NATs that block pure P2P. Usually it's you need a TURN server. You can check this out by trying the demos at demo.easyrtc.com; they are backed by a TURN server. If you were running RTCMultiConnection demo from their site (rather than downloading it to your own), it was probably backed by a TURN server as well.

If you check the easyrtc google group, you'll see this question pop up once a week or so.

I wrote the client side of EasyRTC and answer most of the questions posted on the easyrtc google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/easyrtc).

Comment: Is it a big deal to create own STUN, TURN servers?